# ionic 3 modal full screen width/height for a single modal?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I'm working with ionic modal, I want to resize my modal to full screen, not all the modals but only 1 modal but unable to achieve this as ionic itself is setting width/height properties with **!important** attribute. I've tried to so something like following

```
 @media only screen and (orientation: landscape)  {
   ion-modal {
    .modal-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0 !important;
      left: 0 !important;
      display: block;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 100% !important;
    } 
  }
}
```

when I put this within scope of the page, it doesn't show any effect but when I put this outside of the page's scope, it changes width/height of all the modals in app. I've already searched the web and tried many solutions but none of them worked (or may be I couldn't understand it properly). Any help in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, add a class for your modal:

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create("YourModalPage", null, {
    cssClass:"my-modal"
})
modal.present();
```

Second, now you have `my-modal` class. Style for it in **app.scss**:

```
 @media only screen and (orientation: landscape)  {
   .my-modal {
    .modal-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0 !important;
      left: 0 !important;
      display: block;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 100% !important;
    } 
  }
}
```

**Note that:** Modal element is added outside your page so you can not style for it inside page scope.

Answer (score 1):

Adding css I think this code works fine.

```
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape)  {
   ion-modal {
    .modal-wrapper {
      .modal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0 !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please read the question again. I'm able to implement css to make modal full screen, I'm asking how can I apply this style to specifically ONLY ONE modal.