# How to overwrite alert controller in specific page

Tags: ionic3

I want to overwrite alert box in my ionic 3 application but these are not reflect anymore what i have tried in my page scss

```
.alert-md
{
  max-width:300px !important;
}
```

whats wrong with this?

Comment: check it and give me feedback is it working or not..

Comment: First, you need to add a class to your alert. Then, you use that class to style your alert.See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47193174/4254681) for modal, but the same way for alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using override `scss` in `variable.scss`

**For android**

```
$alert-md-max-width
```

By default **android** max-width is **280px**

**For ios**

```
$alert-ios-max-width
```

By default max-width in **ios** is **270px**

You can also achieve by using `cssClass` inside alert

More details visit [official link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

Comment: I have tried that it works fine. Is it possible to overwrite with in page.

Comment: How can i do that with in page.scss.

Comment: @Urock check it and give it feedback

Comment: I have tried inside page to overerite like this and it works fine thank  you `.alert-md .alert-message{
    color:black;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here how i tried it works fine

```
.alert-md .alert-message{ color:black; white-space: pre-wrap; padding-bottom: 0px; }
```